# How to get the affected rows in stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, informix

If i have a stored procedure ,and i make an insert .

i wanna to return `0 or 1` according to if the insert operation succeeded or not how to do this in `informix` .i wanna to know if there's some thing similar to `@@rowcount` in sql server?.

Example if possible please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can use the following in a stored procedure to extract the rowcount.

```
if dbinfo('sqlca.sqlerrd2') = 0 then
   return 0;
else
   return 1;
end if;
```

(The syntax might be off; it's been years since I used Informix.)

Comment: Could u explain how to use it please?

Comment: added a little example based on my (very) limited experience

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server when you instantiate a new SQlCommand the method ExecuteNonQuery() of the SqlCommand object returns the number of rows affected by that command.
i don't know if the same is possible in informix but you should try using InformixCommand instead of SQlCommand and verify.